# What wrong here in addOrderBy() method of Jooq?

Tags: java, jooq

I am using Jooq and using below code

```
SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery();
```

Now Jooq telling it have a method [Check Here](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/2.5.x/org/jooq/OrderProvider.html#addOrderBy%28java.util.Collection%29) where we can pass Collection and i am doing same, check below

```
 List<SortField<T>> orderByValue1;
```

and then doing this

```
selectQuery.addOrderBy(orderByValue1);
```

but now in the above line i am getting compile time exception

```
The method addOrderBy(Field<?>...) in the type SelectQuery<Record> is not applicable for the arguments (List<SortField<T>>)
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in the jOOQ API, which is described in [issue #2719](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2719). For the time being, the type of your `orderByValue1` list must be adapted:

```
// Correct type:
List<SortField<?>> orderByValue1;

// Wrong type
List<SortField<T>> orderByValue1;
```

Note that the above types are not the same. For more info, consider reading the [Oracle tutorial documentation on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).